# Japanese era "Reiwa" support in Microsoft excel date format

Tags: java, excel, windows, ms-office, date-formatting

We need to show the date in **Japanese era** format.
we are using custom date format "[$-411]ggge ..." to display the date in Japanese era and it is working as expected by showing the dates in Japanese era format based on era defined in system registry level.

we have added new era "Reiwa" with "value name" "2019 05 01" in system registry to support new era **"REIWA"** but the dates entered in that excel cell with date value greater than this new era start date also still showing based previous Japanese calendar era with "value name" "1989 01 08" only.
But my expectation is it should be formatted with respect to new era as the data I have entered is after the new era start date (i.e., 2019/06/30).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System patch to be done or should be upgraded to support new Japanese era with Japanese MSOffice language pack. You should be able to see the new Japanese era in the pc Systemregistry and when you use the Japanese date format , It will be displayed in new era format automatically.